# Apple's background execution example for ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Apple gives [this of background execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html):

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" 
    expirationHandler:^{
    // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
    // stopped or ending the task outright.
    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

// Start the long-running task and return immediately.
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```

This example has never made much sense to me and I've seen it copied to numerous background application examples.

The first thing that doesn't make sense are these two lines in the expirationHandler:

```
[application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
```

It seems like bgTask won't have a value when captured in the block.  The compiler complains as such.  Then below in the dispatch_async the sample shows the same two lines.  I would expect it in the dispatch_async but not in the block.  Can anyone explain why we have these lines in the block?

Also the documentation per beginBackgroundTaskWithName says "Marks the beginning of a new long-running background task."  How exactly is it doing this?  What defines the task?  Is it any code that follows in the block scope?

Comment: `It seems like bgTask won't have a value when captured in the block.`  Why wouldn't it?  Apple also states: `The bgTask variable is a member variable of the class that stores a pointer to the current background task identifier and is initialized prior to its use in this method.`

Comment: you are probably confusing background task identifiers with blocks. So you might have declared the identifier in a scope that doesn't persist. The identifier should be declared in the AppDelegate as a member variable, which will persist as long as your app is alive. This is why both the expiration handler and the dispatch_async both have access to it without "copying it".

Comment: @Pochi, no I'm not confusing the identifier with a block ^.   What I did was accidentally declare it in the local scope and left off the __block yielding the warning  "variable 'bgTask' is uninitialized when captured by block', but I perhaps should not be declaring it in the local scope anyway as you say.   I was referencing this: http://hayageek.com/ios-background-task/

Comment: @william: yes thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4):

```
bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:]
```

tells iOS that your application is starting a new background task.  iOS doesn't care which code comprises the task, it just knows that it needs to give your app more time to execute in the background.

After this line executes, `bgTask` will contain the new background task identifier.

When your background task is complete, you then call `[application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];` and iOS knows that your app has finished the specified background task and may not need any more background execution time (You may still have other background tasks initiated by `beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler` outstanding).

The line:

```
bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
```

is just housekeeping; If you omit this line nothing bad will happen, but `bgTask` will contain an invalid identifier.

If you don't call `endBackgroundTask` before your app's background time expires, then then expiration handler block will be invoked.

In the expiration handler `bgTask` will have the value that was assigned when you called `beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler`, so this is what is passed to `endBackgroundTask` and again assigning `UIBackgroundTaskInvalid` is just housekeeping

Comment: So correct me: Any methods called from any place in an iOS app will normally execute in the main thread unless beginBackgroundTaskWithName is called in which case any methods called after that will execute in the background, up until endBackgroundTask is called.  And if endBackgroundTask is not called within a certain amount of time after  beginBackgroundTaskWithName then iOS will terminate the app.  That is why endBackgroundTask is called a second time in the exp handler just in case the background task didn't finish in the allotted time which I've read and noted myself to be ~10 minutes.

Comment: This is nothing to do with which thread your code executes on. It is simply informing that your app wants to continue performing a task while it is in the background; normally an app will be suspended shortly after it enters the background. Your app has a total of 180 seconds background execution time available before it is terminated.

Comment: I'm still not clear what happens if beginBackgroundTaskWithName/endBackgroundTask pairs are called in different methods.  E.g. in locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations AND in applicationDidEnterBackground:  and I'm not clear about calling a repeating NSTimer from applicationDidEnterBackground.  I.e. if I call it without first calling beginBackgroundTaskWithName the timer won't fire until the app returns to the active state, but if I call beginBackgroundTaskWithName first it will run indefinitely.

Comment: As long as one background task hasn't been ended then your app will continue to run until the background execution time limit is reached or all tasks have been ended. The timer will only run indefinitely if you are running under Xcode. Under normal execution your app will be terminated after 180 seconds of background time (when `backgroundTimeRemaining` reaches 0).  Under Xcode your app continues to run when `backgroundTimeRemaining` reaches 0.

Comment: No, my app runs for up to hours in the background.  FYI it has a live location sharing feature and to send the location data it also needs to keep the network connection.  And the ten minutes is something I've measured happens if one doesn't reset this iOS termination clock.

Comment: Not to differ with you but I have Testflight release builds that run in the background for hours.

Comment: The 180 seconds is elapsed execution time for  [background task execution](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623029-backgroundtimeremaining?language=objc). Other background tasks, such as receiving location updates aren't subject to this timer. Waking up to process a location update takes only a few milliseconds. Try disabling your background location updates and see how long your app runs...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152724/discussion-between-bhartsb-and-paulw11).

Comment: So what I'm still unclear on is what iOS considers a task and how does the ID returned by beginBackgroundTaskWithName associate with it?  In the apple example dispatch_async defines a task, but what if one doesn't call that and for example calls NSTimer that repeats?

Comment: In our offline chat you said per the ID "it is simply a value you need to keep and pass to endBackgroundTask so that the system knows which task is ending"  But what is considered the task?  What bounds it?  For example, if in applicationDidEnterBackground one calls beginBackgroundTaskWithName, but doesn't call dispatch_async and instead calls other methods and then the end of the applicationDidEnterBackground method is reached and endBackgroundTask is never called does the end of applicationDidEnterBackground bound it?

Comment: I'm going to add that in the apple example "// Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks." doesn't make sense to me either since the task only has a certain time to run before iOS kills it unless the time can be reset???